# Share mongoose connection across the node application

Tags: javascript, node.js

Was trying to share a mongoose connection across the node application as a part of practice to learn node,one way  i was able to achieve this was by making use of global as given below

```
global.db = global.db?global.db:mongoose.createconnection("127.0.0.1/test",{useNewUrlParser:true,function(err){console.log(err)}});
```

is there any better approach to achieve this ,one approach that i can think of is using the singleton pattern

Comment: why do you need to multiply the connection?

Comment: Use dependency injection, initialize connection in the root of the project and pass it as a parameter or property throughout the application

Comment: I dont need to multiply connection,i just need to create it once and share across the modules that i'm creating @AlexHunter

Comment: what for? you only need to create one connection

Comment: yes one connection only in the similar way we create config.json and share connection across app  @AlexHunter

Comment: @AyushGupta can you please point me the reference based on the approach you suggested

Comment: I think this two steps will establish the connection overall the application = > var mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myappdatabase');

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS but this will require creating connection in every module where you need it and i dont want that just create connection once and use it across app that is what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node if you `require` the same module multiple times only the first time runs the code in the module. In effect the other `require`s end up getting a reference to the same exported thing. So you can just `require("mongoose")` wherever you need your connection and have the actual connection logic only appear once.

Comment: The problem is, the connection code is asynchronous, so that will cause race conditions during `require`

Comment: @AyushGupta What kind of race conditions are you worried about?

Comment: If there is latency in establishing the connection, and the `require`d variable is used somewhere during startup before the connection initialisation is completed

Comment: @AyushGupta Mongoose buffers requests prior to connection, so there are no race conditions to worry about. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern. It will make mocking and testing a lot easier. For example:

example.model.js

```
class ExampleModel {
  constructor(db) {
    this._db = db;
  }

  doSomething() {
    return this._db.findAll();
  }
}
```

example.service.js

```
class ExampleService {
  constructor(model) {
    this._model = model;
  }

  doSomething() {
    return this._model.doSomething();
  }
}
```

index.js

```
async function run() {
  const conn = await createConnection(); // your connection logic
  const model = new ExampleModel(conn);
  const service = new ExampleService(model);
  const result = await service.doSomething();
  console.log(result);
}

run();
```